# II7 website problems

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I created a second iis 7 website on ws 2008. But I can view it (ie) only from server hosting the website

Any idea will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the address in local and remote?

Comment: Thanks you for you reply The ip address is 10.2 5.124 static

Comment: On client I added dns 10.2.5.124 on network

Comment: I think your problem is about the fire wall. Turn it off and retry.

Comment: I'll try but why I can browse  (chrome or ie) the first created site

Comment: Please more explain, I do not understand you.

Comment: Thanks Farzin I have ws 2008 with running asp.net website abcd.com, I created a second iis website with different header sport.abcd.com wich I can browse only on hosting server

Comment: I mean explain this: *I can browse (chrome or ie)*

Comment: Browse http://abcd.com locally only

Comment: The fire wall is not related to locally site visit, It prevent remote requests if it is not truly configured, Turn it off and test, and let me know the result.

Comment: I ll test it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Before that, ping the sever from client to see if the network has problem.

Comment: hi network is OK i can control the server remotely

Comment: Did you turn off fire wall?

Comment: Did you turn off fire wall?

Comment: yes on and off but still only one website is running ok all added are reacting the same way (local browse only)

Comment: What is the error when you request the website?

Comment: 404 this site can't be reached

Comment: Are the working site and not working site in same folder?

Comment: different folder but same security policy (users access and privilege)

Comment: Please put a html file with name **Index.html** in the folder that have problem, and test that.

Comment: same result (shown only on the server)